# postgresql function creation gives syntax error

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am writing a postgresql function but I cannot seem to find where the error is. Postgresql is at version 9.4.
The following is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_function1()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    DECLARE base_val integer;
    BEGIN
        base_val := (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())::integer * 10000000000);

        IF (currval('custom_sequence') < base_val) THEN
            setval('custom_sequence', base_val);
        END IF;

        NEW.id := custom_function2();
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;
```

My custom_sequence is in the format YYYY0000000000 (ex. 20150000000000).

So what this basically does (should do) is it checks if the base_val (minimum value for current year) is greater then the currval (current custom_sequence value) and updates the custom_sequence value. Then it returns a new value for that sequence generated with the function custom_function2 (which formats it slighly).

When I try to execute this it gives me:
**syntax error at or near "setval"**
I am pretty new to both postgresql and writing functions so I am probably not seeying an obvious error. If someone could help me it would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is related to what's explained in the doc [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT):

> **40.5.2 Executing a Command With No Result**
> [...]
>
> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but
> discard the result, for example when calling a function that has
> side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use
> the PERFORM statement:
>
> PERFORM query;

You should write:

```
PERFORM setval('custom_sequence', base_val);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And thank you for the explanation link